RAID home directory setup
I have ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a SSD. I setup a software RAID5 with 3 HDDs. The RAID is mounted on /mnt/md0
Here is my questions:
I want the home directory to be in the RAID drives instead of the SSD. Basically, users would work from the RAID drives instead because the RAID drives have a lot more space.
I have tried:

useradd -d to add new users in a home directory in /mnt/md0/home/user. But this created login issues, probably snap related, and Firefox doesn't like it.
Someone suggested me to mount /dev/md0, which is my RAID drives to /home. ubuntu REALLY doesn't like it and I couldn't even boot up again and I had to reinstall.

What is the proper way to do it?
Thank you
edit 1:
No I am not using LVM. Seems complicated.

are you using lvm?

Let's make some assumptions

The root filesystem contains /home and is mounted on /
The new home filesystem is to be built from the RAID array /dev/md0 and you've currently got it mounted on /mnt/md0
Users' home directories are to be created under /home, and this is to continue
You've already got some user accounts and these need to be migrated to the new /home filesystem
There is nothing of value on the new home filesystem

It may seem that using LVM is complicated. However, it adds flexibility, as the RAID partition can be used for multiple filesystems or data blocks. If you can guarantee that this isn't a requirement, skip it. However, here is how I would set up LVM. Note that if you take this route it will destroy all data on /dev/md0:
umount /mnt/md0                                           # We are going to replace this

pvcreate /dev/md0                                         # Assign the RAID as a Physical Volume
vgcreate vg /dev/md0                                      # Create the Volume Group
lvcreate --size 500G --name home /dev/vg                  # Create a 500GB Logical Volume called "home"
fs=/dev/vg/home                                           # Assign variable (for later)
mkfs -t ext4 -L home "$fs"                                # Fill the LV with a new filesystem called "home"

If you choose not to go the LVM route I would recommend that you put a dummy partition table on your /dev/md0 and recreate the filesystem there. Note that if you take this route it will destroy all data on /dev/md0:
umount /mnt/md0                                           # We are going to replace this

p() { parted /dev/md0 --align optimal unit MiB "$@"; }
p mklabel gpt                                             # GPT disk label
p mkpart ext4 1 100%                                      # One large partition
p name 1 home                                             # ...called "home"
fs=/dev/md0p1                                             # Assign variable (for later)
mkfs -t ext4 -L home "$fs"                                # New filesystem also called "home"

Or if you are absolutely sure you understand what you're doing, keep the filesystem directly on /dev/md0 without a partition table:
fs=/dev/md0                                               # Just assign variable (for later)

Now you can pick from /dev/vg/home or /dev/md0p1. Hopefully you've assigned $fs already so we can use that here:
mkdir -p /mnt/root                                        # Working space
mount "$fs" /home                                         # New (empty) filesystem is /home
mount --bind / /mnt/root                                  # Ensure old /home is accessible
cp -a /mnt/root/home /home                                # Copy home data
echo 'LABEL=home /home ext4 defaults 0 2' >>/etc/fstab    # Mount filesystem at boot

Reboot at your convenience and ensure everything works as expected. The final step is to remove the data under the old /home from the root filesystem:
mkdir -p /mnt/root                                        # Working space
mount --bind / /mnt/root                                  # Ensure old /home is accessible
find /mnt/root/home -mindepth 1 -depth -delete            # Delete old data
umount /mnt/root

